# How do I configure client authorization for sub-domain.domain.com?

Tags: apache, wamp

I have wamp server with client authentication I generated for specific sub folder:

Now , I want to access my site instead of `https://www.domain.com/subdomain/app1` by using `https://app1.domain.com`

When I try to access the url I do get asked to choose client certificate , but when I choose the matching one I get error 403 forbidden.

When I generated my certificate using OpenSSL , I've used `*.domain.com` as CN for the server key.

Here is my virtual host definition in httpd-ssl.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.domain.com:443
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
ServerAdmin admin@domain.com

ErrorLog "C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/logs/ssl_error.log"
TransferLog "C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/logs/ssl_access.log"

SSLEngine on
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 10

SSLCertificateFile "C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\cert\server.cer"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\cert\server.key"
SSLCACertificateFile "C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\cert\ca.cer"

<LocationMatch ^(?=.*/subomain/app1/)(?!.*/subdomain/app1/service).*>
    SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} eq "App1Key"
</LocationMatch>    

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

CustomLog "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/logs/ssl_request.log" "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

Also , I've created this vhosts.conf to allow `subdomain.domain.com`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\demo\%1"
    ErrorLog "logs\errors.log"
    <directory "C:\wamp\www\demo\%1">
        Options  FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from all
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Update**

I've added the following code to the ssl.conf based on an answer , but now the client certificate always works and it ignores the criteria of the `LocationMatch`

```
<directory "C:\wamp\www\demo\%1">
        Options  FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from all
    </directory>
```

Lets say I want to have the equivalent criteria below to `subdomain.domain.com`

```
<LocationMatch ^(?=.*/subomain/app1//)(?!.*/subomain/app1//service).*>
        #SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData
        SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} eq "Shob"
    </LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not your SSL setup that is giving the 403 forbidden.

Add this at the end of your `<VirtualHost>` block (just before the `</VirtualHost>` although it's only a preference to put it there) to give permissions to access the `DocumentRoot` folder for the virtual host:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www">
    Order allow, deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Or if you're on Apache 2.4 or later:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

You should also check if you had anything else in your previous `<Directory>` block when you had your previous setup, and bring that in too. For example, you might need to `AllowOverride` or set up some `Options` but the above will fix the problem you're asking about.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your answer , I've updated my question and added a different directory and now the site loads , but the problem is that it ignores the location match criteria "SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} eq 'something' "  and I want it to work

Comment: Well you have two mistakes in your LocationMatch, "subomain" instead of "subdomain" and two forward slashes instead of one before "service". But really, I solved your original question so it would be fair to mark my answer accepted. I will try to help with this subsequent problem or you could post another question, which it really is. Actually a third mistake, double forward slash after 'app1' in first part too. Fixing those will hopefully solve it.